# Trouble accessing PostgreSQL database dump

Tags: sql, postgresql, rdbms

I am new to the SQL world so forgive my ignorance.

I have downloaded a postgreSQL dump chemfont.sql (the first downloadable on the page linked below), and I am trying to figure out how to query it.
https://www.chemfont.ca/simple/download

The IT department at my work tried to suggest I search the file for data using string parsing tools like grep, which is not a satisfactory solution. They are now saying that I need to ask someone for permission (from chemfont) to access their database to make SQL queries on the dump file.

It is my understanding that I just need to create my own database in postgreSQL (or any other DBMS), then I can load the data from the .sql file. Is this correct? E.g., this post https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3822/how-do-i-open-a-mysql-database-dump

Comment: Is the `[mysql]` tag spurious?

Comment: Why not try on a local Postgres instance to test your dump?

Comment: What do you mean by "how to query it"? If that is a dump, open a text editor, or import it into a database

Comment: "They are now saying that I need to ask someone for permission (from chemfont) to access their database to make SQL queries on the dump file."  I would suggest you cannot count on your IT department for meaningful help.  Either they are not competent in this area, or they are not rewarded for helping you so they just want you to go away.